# Understanding the limits of bash token substitution

Tags: bash

bash has token substitution, either via the `$()` syntax or via the ``` `` ``` syntax, eg:

```
$ $(echo "echo hi")
hi
```

AFAIK, that works like so:

- first evaluate the inner command: `echo "echo hi"`, which outputs `echo hi`
- then execute the resulting string as a command `echo hi`, which produces `hi`

That being the case, I would have expected the following to write `hi` to file `/tmp/hi`

```
$ $(echo "echo hi > /tmp/hi")
```

but instead, it writes nothing to any file, and outputs:

```
hi > /tmp/hi
```

What's going on here? I originally thought it might be because there are spaces in the string, but the following disconfirms that theory:

```
$ $(echo "echo hi bob")
hi bob
```

Answer (score 2):

The part of `bash`'s manual which applies to your case is this:

> SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION
>
> When  a  simple  command  is executed, the shell performs the following
>          expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right.
>
> 1. The words that the parser has  marked  as  variable  assignments
>                (those  preceding  the  command name) and redirections are **saved
>                for later processing**.
> 2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections  are
>                expanded.   If  any words remain after expansion, the first word
>                is taken to be the name of the command and the  remaining  words
>                are the arguments.
> 3. Redirections are performed as described above under REDIRECTION.
> 4. The text after the = in each variable assignment undergoes tilde
>                expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>                expansion,  and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.

Your `$(echo "echo hi > /tmp/hi")` command substitution will be expanded at point 2, and since the `>` redirection couldn't have been marked for later processing at point 1 (since it only appeared as the result of the command substitution), it will not be performed as per point 3.

If the redirections weren't pre-processed before the expansions, then something like

```
to='>'; echo foo $to bar
```

will echo `foo` into the file `bar`, instead of just echoing `foo > bar` as it does.

Notice that `bash` is different from other shells in the fact that it's also performing split + globbing on the word following a redirection operator (and die with "ambiguous redirect" if it expands to multiple words). For instance, this

```
var='a b'; echo > $var
```

will error out in `bash` instead of clobbering a file named `a b` (as do other shells).